# Iteration of $x \to x^x$

Tags: tetration

If $u(x)=x^x$ then we can form
$$
u^2(x) = \left(x^x \right)^{x^x} = x^{x^{x+1}}
$$
some simplification occurs, but the further iterates are a typographical challenge to mathjax.

Writing $E_k$ for $u^k(x)$ we have 
$$
E_0 =x \\
E_{n+1} = u(E_n) = E_n^{E_n}.
$$
However, each term in the sequence is a power of $E_0 = x$ so we may also write
$$
E_n = x^{P_n}
$$
where
$$\begin{align}
P_0 &= 1\\
P_1 &= x \\
P_2 &= x^{x+1}
\end{align}
$$
the iteration gives
$$
E_{n+1} = E_n^{E_n} = \left(x^{P_n}\right)^{x^{P_n}} = x^{P_nx^{P_n}}
$$
so that 
$$
P_{n+1}=P_n x^{P_n}.
$$
We note that $P_k$ is also a power of $x$, say $P_n=x^{Q_n}$ which gives
$$
P_{n+1} = x^{P_n+Q_n}
$$
it seems that each iteration takes us one step further up the ladder of tetration, but i do not know the notation to express this in a precise symbolic form. can anyone help?

Comment: apology - due to imminent travel, i may not be able to respond to comments until tomorrow

Comment: I am not precisely sure what you are after, but you might want to look up "Knuth's up-arrow" notation. $a\uparrow b$ means $a^b$ while $a\uparrow\uparrow b$ means taking $a$ to its own power $b$-times. For example, $a\uparrow\uparrow2=a^{a^a}$.

Comment: @user1729 yes, thx, that is the sort of thing i'm looking for, the $\uparrow\uparrow$ symbol seems a little clumsy visually, perhaps only because i am not used to writing $a^b$ as $a \uparrow b$. however one specific notational problem in the present case is that we have $x \uparrow (x \uparrow  (x ... \uparrow f(x))...))$ where all "exponents" are $x$ except the final (innermost) one, which is a function of $x$ (or, rather, that is what i would like to show. but i can't even write this claim down at the moment, apart from describing it informally in ordinary language

Comment: If I recall correctly then Heryk Trappmann had made his PhD thesis (in german) about symmetric algebraic operations, and $x \to x^x$ was one of its subjects. Try to find it via "Tetration Forum" (Sorry, I'm lazy to search it for you)

Comment: thx Gottfried, interesting link.

Comment: If you look at $g(y)=(1+y)^{(1+y)}-1$ instead you can expand it into a power series and study the emerging pattern of coefficients when iterating (however I don't know whether this helps really). After iterating you use $f(x,h)=g(x-1,h)+1$ where $h$ is the iteration-height to evaluate the original iteration

Answer (score 1):

Extending my earlier comment. First we write $f(x)=x^x$ and $f(x,h)=f(f(x,h-1))$ , $f(x,0)=x$ and $f(x,1)=f(x)$ where $h$ indicates the "iteration-height". Then we consider the function $g(x,h)=f(x+1,h)-1$ and get a nicely iterable power series for $g(x)$ . The coefficients of $g(x,h)$ depend on $h$ and are in fact polynomials in $h$ of increasing order. The first few coefficients are
$$ \begin{array} {rrrlrrrr} g(x,h) &= & x  \cdot & (1 &&&&) \\
 & +& x^2 \cdot & (&1 \cdot h&&&) \\ 
 & +& x^3 \cdot & (&-1/2 \cdot  h & + 1  \cdot h^2&&) \\ 
 & +& x^4 \cdot & (& 7/12  \cdot  h & -5/4   \cdot h^2 & + 1  \cdot  h^3&) \\ 
 & \vdots &  \vdots
\end{array}$$
After that, the actual evaluation to any arbitrary iteration-height (I think: even fractional height) can be done by evaluating $g(x)$ at $x-1$ because $$f(x,h)=g(x-1,h)+1$$

However, the next step must be to determine the range of convergence by analyzing the pattern of the coefficients in the polynomial to determine the "general term" for the polynomials in $g(x,h)$.
The convergence-radius might easily be zero, especially for the fractional iterates, but if this is the case then possibly a summation-method for divergent series can still help.